# Zip file saving wrong in python

Tags: python, zip

Instead of saving the zip file made from C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder as ZipFile.zip/Folder it is saving the zip file as ZipFile.zip/Users/User/Desktop/Folder

Python variables used below:

Code below:

```
backUp = raw_input("> ")
backDevice = raw_input("> ")
backZip = raw_input("> ")
dest = backDevice + "/BackUp"

bkZip = zipfile.ZipFile(os.path.join(dest, backZip), 'w')
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(backUp):
    bkZip.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        bkZip.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))
bkZip.close()
```

Comment: Could you add some more code so I can see what the variables used are originally valued at?

Comment: I just finished it, if you need I can add the entire code because above each raw_input is also a print, which is basically all that's left that isn't shown, are the print commands.

Comment: What are you typing in for the input?

Comment: For backUp I use `C:/Users/TheCryptek/Desktop/BootStrap`. For BackDevice I use `E:/` and for backZip I use `Backup.zip`

Comment: You can find the entire script here `http://pastebin.com/kgMxBzyR`

Comment: Firstly, line 44 and 45 are a bit off but that hopefully won't effect anything. So the issue is with what files it is backing up, correct?

Comment: No the issue is how it is savign the zip file

Comment: It is saving every directory up to the directory full of files, so you have to run through each directory before getting to the specified directory to back up inside the zip file

Comment: Have you tried altering dest to `
dest = os.path.join(backDevice , "BackUp")` and replacing any reference to any form of backdevice + "BackUp" with dest? That may be causing some issues

Comment: Yea but upon doing so I get greeted with `  File "UBU.py", line 44
    if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(backdevice, "BackUp"):
                                                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
`

Comment: That's because you forgot a )